# Regex in Apache Pig to extract required data

Tags: regex, apache-pig

I have the sample data like below. I am trying to extract ip address and date column which is in square brackets and the **"GET /demo HTTP/1.1"**

**361.631.17.30 - - [11/Aug/2012:07:23:32 -0500] "GET /demo HTTP/1.1"** 200 0 "/demo" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0-rc4")

This is the first time I am using REGEX Expressions. After breaking my head the whole day i have written something like below, Also could someone point me to basic resources to learn REGEX. I have been using some sites like https://regex101.com/ but if i paste the same command in apache pig it throws me errors.

I have tried the below command but it doesn't work.

**REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'^(\S+)([\w])+\s([+-]\d{4})\'] as (ipaddress:chararray, datecol:chararray, client:chararray);**

Comment: Try `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '^(\\S+)\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\[(.*?)\\]\\s+"([^"]*)"' as (ipaddress:chararray, datecol:chararray, client:chararray);`

Comment: I get the error after running the command you provided. Caused by: org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1031: Incompatable schema: left is "ipaddress:chararray,datecolumn:chararray,client:chararray", right is "org.apache.pig.builtin.regex_extract_all_line_1:tuple()"

Comment: And if you replace `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` with `REGEX_EXTRACT`? Post full code.

Comment: I get the same error

Comment: REGISTER /linkto/piggybank.jar
A = load 'weblogs_rebuild.txt' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(line,'^(\\S+)\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\[(.*?)\\]\\s+"([^"]*)"') AS
(ipaddress: chararray, datecolumn: chararray, client: chararray);
dump B;

Comment: Try `B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(
      REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(LINE, '^(\\S+)\\s+\\S+\\s+\\S+\\s+\\[(.*?)\\]\\s+"([^"]*)".*'))
       AS (ipaddress:chararray, datecol:chararray, client:chararray), LINE;`

Comment: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 5, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : "" . column 5 comes at dump B;